# How can I configure Azure DevOps Server Environment agent as I keep getting VS30063 error?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020

I have an installation of Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.1 which is running on a EC2 windows virtual machine (Server 2019). I have been able to install an instance of the agent that is running as a build agent but when I try to install a copy of the agent as an Environment agent it is giving me VS30063: You are not authorized to access . I have a valid PAT that has been given full permissions. When I installed the build agent I had to give the url as https://[FQDN]/Sandbox where Sandbox is the name of my collection, however when installing an Environment agent it doesn't like this format of the url and insists on it being https://[FQDN]. I have configured IIS to only have the https binding and have allowed both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication. The FQDN exists in DNS but is overwritten in the hosts file because of a network load balancer that the FQDN points to which sits in front of the server, this is because the NLB did not like traffic coming from the server and going back to itself.

Can someone please help me with what I need to do to allow access using the PAT token.

BTW the PAT was generated for a user that is an administrator as configured in the Azure DevOps console.

The command that I run in powershell is:

```
.\config.cmd --environment `
    --agent ${Env:computername} `
    --url "$(${Env:AZP_URL})" `
    --auth PAT `
    --token "$(Get-Content ${Env:AZP_TOKEN_FILE})" `
    --work '_work' `
    --sslskipcertvalidation `
    --runasservice `
    --environmentname ${Env:AZP_ENVIRONMENT_NAME} `
    --collectionname ${Env:AZP_COLLECTION_NAME} `
    --projectname ${Env:AZP_PROJECT_NAME} `
    --addvirtualmachineresourcetags `
    --virtualmachineresourcetags ${Env:AZP_ENVIRONMENT_TAGS}
```

I am trying to do this in a docker container but have also tried running the agent install directly on the server and get the same error there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default the PAT organization level is set to current `Collection` level scope (in your scenario, it should be `https://[FQDN]/Sandbox`). But in the script to setup Environment agent, the URL is specified to the server level (`https://[FQDN]`).

So, in this case, you need to edit the PAT and change the organization level to “`All accessible organizations`”.

[image]